# Rx SerialDispatchQueueScheduler doesn't seem to make the code run in serial sequence

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, rx-swift

I have a problem with an `Observable<Data?>` `function` that is called so many times and so fast that the `function` doesn't complete until the next one is run. This makes sense and is good in most cases. But in this case it becomes very problematic because the `function` in question uses a `counter`.

```
func sendMessage(input: MessageToSend) -> Observable<Data?> {
    input.counter = self.counter

    print("-- 1", input.counter)

    let transformMessage = transform(message: input)
    self.counter += 1

    print("-- 2", input.counter)

    return transformMessage
}
```

Obviously I need `input.counter` to increase by 1 every time the `function` is called. But unfortunately this isn't what's happening. Because of the `async` nature of `rx` `sendMessage()` is run and adds 0 to `input.counter`, but before it has had the chance to increment `self.counter` by 1, `sendMessage()` is run again and again adds 0 to `input.counter`. Then the first call reaches `self.counter += 1`, and immediately after, the second call reaches `self.counter += 1` as well. So now the counter has reached 2. So when the third call is made, `input.counter` gets 2 as value.

The prints will look like this:

```
-- 1 0
-- 1 0
-- 2 0
-- 2 0
-- 1 2
-- 2 2
```

My initial idea on how to fix this was to force the call to a `serial` `task`. So instead of calling it like this:

```
disposeble = tsiHandler?.sendMessage(message: message).subscribe()
```

I called it like this:

```
disposeble = tsiHandler?.sendMessage(message: message)
    .subscribeOn(SerialDispatchQueueScheduler(internalSerialQueueName: "serial"))
    .subscribe()
```

In my world this would force it to become `serial` which would make all the calls to `sendMessage()` wait for other calls to complete. But for some reason it doesn't work. I get the exact same result in the prints. Am I missunderstanding how `SerialDispatchQueueScheduler` work?

Comment: What is calling `sendMessage(message:)` so quickly? There is nothing in the code you showed that would do that...

Answer (score 1):

As it is written, each call to sendMessage is being placed on a *different* scheduler, so even if the schedulers are serial, that wouldn't accomplish what you are trying to do. Instead of creating a new scheduler for each call, have them all use the same scheduler.

Even so, this code looks fishy and your comments about it implies a fundamental misunderstanding of Rx. For example it is not inherently async. It merely sets up callback chains...

Comment: Thanks for your response! Could you elaborate a bit? How do I use the same scheduler? I thought I already did that. Or do you mean that every time it hooks on `onSubscribe()` it's a new serial task that doesn't consider the old one?

Comment: No, I mean that `SerialDispatchQueueScheduler(internalSerialQueueName: "serial")` is a constructor. You are literally making a new scheduler every time that is called. Just call the constructor once and store the instance, then reuse that instance here.

Comment: Depending on how `transform(message:)` is implemented, the `subscribeOn(_:)` probably doesn't do what you think it does anyway...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should make sure:

1. To hold **one** instance of the `SerialDispatchQueueScheduler`.
2. When sending a message you have to `observe(on: scheduler)` and not `subscribe(on: scheduler)`.

Hope that helps.